# Meshing a cylindrical geometry with a notch

Tags: plotting, mesh, finite-element-method

I have been trying to mesh a cylindrical geometry with a notch. To generate the geometry i use the following command.

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
 reg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 0.25];
 Region[reg1];
 reg2 = RegionProduct[reg1, Line[{{0}, {2}}]];
 Region[reg2];
 reg3 = Cuboid[{-0.25, -0.1, 0.9}, {-0.15, 0.1, 1.1}];
 Region[reg3];
 reg4 = RegionDifference[reg2, reg3];
 RegionPlot3D[reg4, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]
I am trying to mesh this geometry using linear Tetrahederal elements using the script

```
ToElementMesh[reg4, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Volume" -> 0.001},"MeshOrder" -> 1]
```

I get the following error

```
ToElementMesh::femtemnbb: The bounds for BooleanRegion[#1&&!#2&, 
{Cylinder[{{0,0,0},{0,0,2}},0.25],Cuboid[{-0.25,-0.1,0.9},{-0.15,0.1,1.1}]}] 
are {{-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]},{-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]},{-\[Infinity],\ 
[Infinity]}}. Unless finite numeric bounds are specified, the mesh generation 
will constrain the region to have finite bounds.
```

I will grateful if i could get any help on this issue or if there is a another way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an alternative with exact numbers:

```
r = RegionDifference[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}, 1/4], 
   Cuboid[{-1/4, -1/10, 9/10}, {-15/100, 1/10, 11/10}]];
m = ToElementMesh[r, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Volume" -> 0.001}, 
  "MeshOrder" -> 1]
```

But since you want a fist order mesh you could also discretize the regions first and then construct the region difference. This would allow for a good intersection of the regions:

```
r = RegionDifference[
   DiscretizeRegion@Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}, 1/4], 
   DiscretizeRegion@
    Cuboid[{-1/4, -1/10, 9/10}, {-15/100, 1/10, 11/10}]];
m = ToElementMesh[r, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Volume" -> 0.001}, 
  "MeshOrder" -> 1]

m["Wireframe"[PlotRange -> {8/10, 12/10}]]
```

[image]

This will requite a few more elements but it might be worth it.

Comment: @user21Thanks, this is a good alternative, especially that fine mesh is required at the intersecting regions.

Answer (score 8):

The issue can be [addressed](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/message/ToElementMesh/femtemnbb.html) by specifying explicit numerical bounds:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
reg=RegionDifference[
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}, 1/4],
  Cuboid[{-0.25, -0.1, 0.9}, {-0.15, 0.1, 1.1}]];
RegionPlot3D[reg,PlotPoints->100]
ToElementMesh[reg, {{-1/4,1/4}, {-1/4, 1/4},{0,2}}]
```

Comment: @YoungThanks, this works.

Comment: +1 for referencing a message page!

Comment: @user21Thanks, i forgot to do that last time.

Comment: @KVK318, thanks!